# Failed Remove Anaconda Package (InvalidArchiveError)

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda, uninstallation

I accidentally install tensorflow-gpu using `conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu` in my base environment. When I try to remove that use the commands

```
conda clean -a
conda remove tensorflow-gpu
```

It return InvalidArchiveError

> InvalidArchiveError('Error with archive
>   C:\Users\Path\Anaconda3\pkgs\openssl-1.1.1g-he774522_0u1c8dqql\pkg-openssl-1.1.1g-he774522_0.tar.zst.
>   You probably need to delete and re-download or re-create this file. 
>   Message from libarchive was:\n\nCould not unlink')

how to completely remove tensorflow-gpu package in my base conda environment?

Comment: Is your issue resolved now ? Else, please remove `openssl-1.1.1g-he774522_0.tar.zst` and number of folders `openssl-1.1.1g-he774522_0` containing also those `.tar balls`. After that please close the terminal which was running using `openssl` so if your python is running somewhere, try to close it down.  Reopen and install `openssl` and everything will be back to normal.

Comment: Thank You! Yes, my issue resolved by reinstalling Anaconda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing the solution here (Answer Section), even though it is present in the Comment Section for the benefit of the community.

This issue can be resolved in two methods

***First Method***:  Remove `openssl-1.1.1g-he774522_0.tar.zst` and number of folders `openssl-1.1.1g-he774522_0` containing also those `.tar balls`. After that please close the terminal which was running using `openssl` so if your python is running somewhere, try to close it down. Reopen and install `openssl` and everything will be back to normal

```
# install openssl from libarchive
conda install -c conda-forge libarchive
```

***Second Method*** : Reinstall Anaconda

Answer (score 0):

try: conda remove --force tensorflow-gpu